# Remove angle border UIButton ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, border

How to remove this white border around the angles in the shown button?

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your snippet code here where you construct your button?

Comment: try to add more code than just UIColor.blackColor.CGColor.

Comment: please show how you instantiate your UIButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your button this way:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
```